# Devise: update password succeeds without password confirmation & without respecting min length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

In my registrations edit form, I have the basic password change logic implemented. When I wanted to style the error messages, I tested the functionality for the first time and I ran into two major issues:

- password changes without it respecting the min. length set in the config file
- password changes without the password confirmation

This only happens on the second try! First form submit shows the correct error messages, if I send the data (click the submit button) a second time: tadaaa - logged out and password changed. I don't even know what else to add, it is one of the most basic concepts of authentication.

What am I missing? Anyone has experience with this issue?

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# ==> Configuration for :validatable
# Range for password length.
config.password_length = 6..128
```

**user.rb**

```
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

**registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label       :change_password,
                  class: 'user__password-change' %>
<%= f.input       :password,
                  hint: "leave it blank if you don't want to change it",
                  required: false,
                  error: false %>
<%= f.error       :password, class: 'form-error' %>
<%= f.input       :password_confirmation,
                  required: false,
                  error: false %>
<%= f.error       :password_confirmation, class: 'form-error' %>
```

I know that I have a `required: false` on both, but this basically just takes the asterisk away.

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    super
    @user.update(country: set_country, city: set_city)

    @couch = @user.couch
    @couchfacilities = @couch.couch_facilities
    update_couch
    update_couch_facilities

    if offers_couch == "0"
      set_couch_inactive
    elsif offers_couch == "1"
      set_couch_active
    end

    @usercharacteristics = @user.user_characteristics
    update_user_characteristics
  end
```

Comment: don't see any validation checking, not clear what controller you've inherited from to override, and a lot going on BESIDES changing the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue here is that you have not approached customizing the Devise controller in a good way at all.

Lets start by looking at how the super method is implemented:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      set_flash_message_for_update(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email)
      bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name if sign_in_after_change_password?

      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

As you have implemented it now your code is being executed way after the response has already been decided. You added a ton of additional code paths as well as each additional update may fail which are not handled at all.

If you want to tap into the flow and do something to the resource after it has been saved pass but before the response is rendered pass a block to super:

```
def update
  super do |resource|
    resource.update(country: set_country, city: set_city)
  end
end
```

If you want to instead do something before its saved override the `update_resource` method:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.assign_attributes(
    country: set_country, city: set_city
  )
  super(resource, params)
end
```

You should also consider if you really need to jam all this functionality into a single endpoint.

Comment: Hi max, thanks for your feedback! It's the first Rails app I am building, so I don't have much experience. Your feedback is very valuable to me. I will absorb it and see if any questions are open / if I can solve the current problems.

Comment: @LisbethPurrucker customizing Devise can be pretty tricky as its a very complex beast due to the amount of modularity built into it. I would check the Wiki and just do one additional feature at a time and make sure you cover your additional feature thoughly with tests. Its not really clear what you're doing here but it kind of looks like something that can be approached by using nested attributes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: What I did for now is basically put all my logic first and then call super and all my problems disappear. I am very thankful for the other feedback, but I actually can't have the logic anywhere else. And yes, I am using nested attributes already.